# Calling getItem() on DynamoDB object from AWS Lambda, why doesn't my callback execute?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to get an item from my DynamoDB database. The way my code is presently written, I fail to retrieve any data from DynamoDB. I must be doing something wrong, because as far as I can tell from my test, my callback is not being called.

I spent all day on this yesterday and have been tinkering with it unsuccessfully since I woke up this morning.

If anyone can provide insight into what I'm doing wrong here, I would be very grateful. Thanks to everyone in advance!

Final note: The timeout on the Lambda function itself is set to 5 minutes. So I don't think the Lambda function is timing out before the db query can return. When I run the function, it exits after only a moment.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var response = null;
var test = false;

function getFromDB(callback) {
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env['DB_TABLE_NAME'] // evaluates to 'test-table',
    Key: {
      "id": {
        S: postId // evaluates to a big string, pulling it in from an SNS message. Verified it with console.log(). It stores the expected value.
      }
    }
  };
  dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) callback(data, true);           // an error occurred
    else     callback(data, true);           // successful response
  });
}

getFromDB((data, isCalled) => {
    response = data;
    test = isCalled;
});

console.log(data); // evaluates to null
console.log(test); // evaluates to false
```

Comment: Have you checked your logs? In the AWS console click on your lambda function, then click monitoring tab, then click 'View in Cloudwatch'. The top item will be your latest execution log.

Comment: Also, what is your handler set to?

Comment: Your handler function can optionally take callback as an argument, but I think you have to take event and context. Like this 'function(event, context, callback)'

Comment: Thanks for continuing to look into this. I'll check my logs today after work to see if that can help.

Comment: handler signature is (event, context);

Comment: CloudWatch log says "process exited before completing request"

Comment: That could be a problem. Your handler probably needs to be (event, context, callback) - if you are planning to return some data from the Lambda. Can you post your whole function?

Comment: Also, try writing some debug to the console. That will show up in cloudwatch and you can pin down how far your function is getting. Take a read though [this guide too](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html).

Comment: BTW does the handler in the console match the handler name in your code?

Comment: 1. Have you tried adding `callback(null, "Hello World")` to the top—does it run? If it does, the issue is in your db query, otherwise it is your lambda set-up.

2. I believe the default arguments for your lambda handler should be `(event, context, callback)`.

Answer (score 5):

I Had faced similar issue.
I removed async in the statement below to resolve :

```
exports.handler = async (event,context)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what's going on is Lambda calls the function, but it's not going to wait for the call back, so it thinks it is done and exits.

I think I had a similar problem and resolved it by using Bluebird and async/await.

I can provide a snippet from my code if you need it

Answer (score 1):

Have you loaded the SDK? I can't see it in your code snippet

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});
```

EDIT: Included region

Comment: Yes, the SDK has been loaded. I'll edit my original post to reflect that.

Comment: I didn't include the `AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});` statement. Do you think that could be causing my issue?

Comment: Its possible. Dynamo requires a region and I dont think it defaults to anything. But without a stack trace its difficult to know what your problem  might be. Let me know if you need more info on regions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try and see if it takes care of the issue.

Comment: I updated the code to include the region, but it still doesn't work.